# Quills JS: extracting formatted text, saving it on server, loading it and identifying specific parts

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, quill

For a project I am trying to make a message / newsletter system to function on a website.
I am using Quill JS as my RTE that loads a template whenever the editor is opened.
Upon sending the message it saves an html copy of the message to the server with an ID
Saving the content of editor in a form on submit

```
<input type="hidden" name="doctext" id="doctext" value='<?php echo $doctext; ?>'>
```

Writing the content to file (PHP)

```
$doctext = trim($_POST["doctext"]);
$myfile = fopen("$postid.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $doctext;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
```

Now I want to make a feed that lists all of the messages / newsletters with the headline and a sample of the content. Unfortunately Quill JS removes / doesn't use any ids for the HTML in the editor and it is therefore hard to identify the headline and content area.
The only solution that I can see is to put in some invisible text before and after the headline and content, that will be visible in the HTML, but I know that this would never be approved for a real system.
I know my way around HTML and CSS fine, but when it comes to PHP and JS I am not that comfortable.
There is probably a cool tool / solution out there that I don't know about and I would be happy to receive any insight to a more proper solution.

Edit: I can see that even in the delta(s) format, there aren't any identifiers.

Edit: JS QUILL code:

```
var Size = Quill.import('attributors/style/size');
Size.whitelist = ['0px', '12px','16px','20px','24px', '28px', '32px',
'36px'];
Quill.register(Size, true);

const Block = Quill.import('blots/block');

  class Overskrift extends Block {}
  Overskrift.blotName = 'overskrift';
  Overskrift.tagName = 'p';
  Overskrift.className = 'overskrift-class';
  Quill.register(Overskrift, true);

var toolbarOptions = [
['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
[{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
['image'],
[{ 'size': ['12px', '16px', '20px', '24px', '28px', '32px', '36px'] }],
[{ 'align': ''}, {'align': 'center'}, {'align': 'right'}],

];

var Delta = Quill.import('delta');



var quill = new Quill("#texteditor", {
theme: 'snow',
modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
}
});
```

Best regards
Martin Pedersen

Comment: Hello Martin, I didnt 100% understand your problem. So want to identify parts of the content in your Quill editor, right? and in your case you have a headline and a content. So you are suggesting that they can have ids like <p id="headline">..</p><p id="content">..</p>, am I correct?

Comment: Hello Hassan, you are not totally off, but no. I want to save the text I have in my editor to either html or delta format. I then want to open the file and find the headline and content area, but because Quill strips away any classes or ids and applies their formatting inline, it is not possible to simply look up the id of the text segment. I hope this clarifies things

Comment: How are you adding those ids and classes from the first place?

Comment: In the div that contains my editor I just add a segment like <p><span id="something"> Headline </span></p> and Quill turns that into <p><strong style="font-size: 28px;"> Headline </strong></p>

Comment: I see, now I can give you a solution 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make Quill keep/add a certain class for an element, you have to configure it manually through Quill instead of adding them yourself.

You can achieve that by:

```
  const Block = Quill.import('blots/block');

  class HeadLine extends Block {}
  HeadLine.blotName = 'headline';
  HeadLine.tagName = 'h1';
  HeadLine.className = 'headline-class';
  Quill.register(HeadLine, true);
```

This will add/remove the headline-class for the h1 class when you use the headline blot. and if you want to have more control on the headline element you can do:

```
  class HeadLine extends Block {
    static create(value) {
      const node = super.create(value);
      node.classList.add('headline-class');
      return node;
    }
  }
```

And to set the contents of the editor you can do:

```
quill.setContents('{"ops":[{"insert":"Headline"},{"attributes":{"headline":true},"insert":"\n"},{"insert":"\n\ncontent"},{"attributes":{"content":true},"insert":"\n"}]}')
```

Now you have full control on the node itself.

Also, I created a jsFiddle that I hope it helps you:

https://jsfiddle.net/hassansalem/c5nvgfq1/6/

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. The fiddle looks great and works, but when I input your code to my JS I get a syntax error: "redeclaration of let HeadLine". I haven't declared a variable HeadLine anywhere though.

Comment: That is nice, you may have another HeadLine defined somewhere else. Just try to change the name of the class in your code, like instead of HeadLine to HeadLine1 just to try if it works. I updated the jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hassansalem/c5nvgfq1/8/

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same syntax error, but with the new name. I tried 3 really obscure ones just to make sure it wasn't declared anywhere.

Comment: I added the entire quill segment of my js file which is run from the html page with <script src="../js/scripts.js"></script>

Comment: Can you paste your code in this codeShare: https://codeshare.io/G7A87b please paste it with the code you copied from my jsFiddle. Also with the name changes as well

Comment: I found the issue with the syntax error. It is because I accidentally called the JS script twice in the HTML, so the second time it tries to change the const. So your fiddle allows for me to assign the class to the text in the editor, but how do I assign it to my template text?

Comment: Good to know. Now you can set the contents of the editor by using quill.setContents. And it accepts delta object. for your example it could be: quill.setContents('{"ops":[{"insert":"aaa"},{"attributes":{"headline":true},"insert":"\n"},{"insert":"\n\nbbb"},{"attributes":{"content":true},"insert":"\n"}]}')

Comment: Thank you, so much, I was actually using setContents to put in the delta object from local storage if the page was left by accident. I kind of just expected it to be done directly from the HTML page, but I guess it makes sense to keep it in the JS. I will mark your solution, but I might comment again whenever I run into my next problem :) Can you think of a way to mark the end of the headline whenever the author has edited the template?

Comment: That would be a more complex scenario than adding a class or attribute to a blot. I would suggest starting from this solution already and instead of having just <h1> or <div> you can create some placeholder that has an editable area surrounded by uneditable one. I have dropped a simple example in the jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hassansalem/rjhnv4gz/1/

Comment: Thank you, so much. This has certainly given me something to work with.